# Shell string manipulation not working in Applescript

Tags: applescript, bash

I'm trying to make a service to translate things which Chrome doesn't translate automatically. The following script works when run from my shell

```
#!/bin/bash

input='это тест)))' # translates to - this is a test)))
if [[ $(echo "$input") =~ ')' ]]; then 
    input="$(echo "${input//)/}")"
fi
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"; /usr/local/bin/trans -e yandex -b :en "$input"
```

the result: `this is a test`

However when I put this into an Applescript:

```
set input to "это тест)))"
set output to (do shell script "if [[ $(echo " & quoted form of input & ") =~ ')' ]]; then " & quoted form of input & "=\"$(echo \"${" & quoted form of input & "//)/}\")\"; fi; export PATH=\"/usr/local/bin:$PATH\"; /usr/local/bin/trans -e google -b :en " & quoted form of input & "")

display dialog output as string
```

The result is still `this is a test)))`

It still runs and translates the input string. But it doesn't remove the `)))`. I don't understand why the `if` statement is not working in my applescript version. Am I quoting something wrong?

This script uses a program called **Translate-Shell** which can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/soimort/translate-shell) or at the program author's website [here](https://www.soimort.org/translate-shell/).

Comment: Where did `trans` come from as it's not a native OS X app included in the OS X installation, so I'm unable to reproduce your command line for testing. Is there a native OS X binary available from somewhere or the source code so I can compile it directly as I don't use the typical package managers, e.g Homebrew?

Comment: My apologies. I completely overlooked that. `trans` is  **translate-shell** which can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/soimort/translate-shell) or at the authors own website [here](https://www.soimort.org/translate-shell/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because, the shell try to change a 'string', not to set a variable.

The command as example:

```
do shell script "if [[ $(echo " & quoted form of input & ") =~ ')' ]]; then " & quoted form of input & "=\"$(echo \"${" & quoted form of input & "//)/}\")\"; fi; "
```

After the concatenation (Look at the **Events** in the script editor), the command is:

> do shell script "if [[ $(echo 'это тест)))') =~ ')' ]]; then 'это
>   тест)))'=\"$(echo \"${'это тест)))'//)/}\")\"; fi; "

---

So, put the content of the **AppleScript**'s variable into a variable in the shell (I remove the **echo** commands, because it's useless), like this:

```
set input to "это тест)))"
set output to do shell script "input=" & (quoted form of input) & "; if [[  \"$input\" =~ ')' ]]; then input=${input//)/}; fi; export PATH=\"/usr/local/bin:$PATH\"; /usr/local/bin/trans -e google -b :en \"$input\""
display dialog output
```